# How to get rid of google pop-ups while testing and navigation google url?

Tags: selenium, testing

[image: google message]

Every time I navigate to google through Selenium, I encounter this popup. I can't click on the search bar. Is there a way to close permanently this popup without using any JS alert method etc.?

I tried some extensions but it didn't work

Comment: Why you don't click on "Accept cookies" when you navigate? Once this done, you can make the search

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the Lock button () on the top-left of the search box
2. Click on 'Cookies'
3. Make sure you're on 'allowed' and find anything on the lines of `google.com`
4. Click Block, Done and refresh the page

Additionally, you may want to try it first without the web-driver 'Chrome is being controlled by automated test software' mode, so open Google Chrome you way you usually would.